# Dropdown Menus Appearing Behind Flash Video

Tags: flash, video, drop-down-menu, overlay, z-index

My drop down menus are appearing behind my flash videos (JW Player) in Chrome and Internet Explorer. The problem does not occur in FireFox and Safari.

I've read so many solutions relating to changing the wmode and the z-index of the nav and video, with no success.

You can see the issue on the sixth slide in the slider: http://ghostpool.com/wordpress/supermassive/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

just add this as first param :

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

Comment: The object code is generated using javascript. I did use a piece of javascript to auto insert that parameter but can no longer find it and I do not believe it fixed the issue anyway.

Comment: @GhostPool: Hmmm, that could be problematic, as this parameter is IIRC only read in when the Flash object is loaded (and therefore needs to be in the object right from the start). Could you modify the generation code, or destroy the Flash object and re-create it with this parameter?

Comment: So you can add it on the fly like this : jQuery("object").append('<param name="wmode" value="transparent">');

Comment: @Piskvor: I wouldn't know that is a little bit beyond my skills.

Comment: Excellent that works in Chrome. However using that code causes the slider to stop functioning in IE. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

use this method

```
 <object id="flash1" data="one.swf" height="500" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="800">
 <param name="movie" value="one.swf" />
 <param name="quality" value="High" />
 <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
 <param name="menu" value="false" />
 </object>
```

Answer (score 0):

We had also this issue with Flash movies in front of the menu.
In IE 11 with SharePoint 2013 we could fix the issue as follows:

We add the content editor web part and edited the code. We insert the object together with the "ms-wpContentDivSpace" class:

```
<div class="ms-wpContentDivSpace">
    <object width="800" height="500" id="flash1" data="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YouTubeID" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent"><param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YouTubeID"/><param name="quality" value="high"/>
    </object>
</div>
```